# Form printed by echo doesn't submit

Tags: php, forms

I have the following form in my `header2.php`:

```
echo '<form action="includes/login.php" method="POST">
  <input  type="text" name="uid" placeholder="Username/e-mail">
  <input  type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Login</button></form>';
```

I have set up my database credentials in my live host but I can't seem to get my login page to work. I think the problem could be in the `header2.php` file but not sure. I have turned on error reporting but I got an HTTP 500 error. Is this code correct on a live server?

Comment: 500 error means something on the page you submit to has broken - you need to show the server side code that processes the login

Comment: I am just wondering if my form action is correct because I know that I have to use the __DIR__ for include

Comment: I am still getting the 500 error at times even when doing a simple form action to another file....